# .NET Gridview themes examples

Tags: .net, css, gridview, themes

I'm looking for examples for .net gridView themes (css files) to get ideas for my grid.

My grid must have a double-pager look (Bottom & Top) and should support sorting (by clicking on headers) and row highlighting when moving the mouse.

The only one I found online was the Glassy Black
(http://weblogs.asp.net/kevinbrammer/archive/2008/02/24/glassy-black-gridview-theme.aspx)

Do you have any other websites I can learn from?

(I'd be happier if it included source code examples, but if not - it's also good, css and html are readable)

Comment: as of 7.23.2015 the Glassy Black example webpage appears to not be working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gridview are rendered as HTML Tables. So any Table themes would get the job done.
For headers, footers and other stuff you might have to code the css your self.

Check out these links.

**Update 24/15 - mattberseth.com dead - updated links with archive.org**

http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/index.php?css=69#r69

https://web.archive.org/web/20110303235607/http://mattberseth2.com/demo/ has lot of gridview customizations with code download.

[Paging](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=Using+a+DataPager+with+the+GridView+Control+-+Implementing+IPageableItemContainer&Filter=All)

[Paging With Slider](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=A+Slider+DataPager+with+Dynamic+Tooltips&Filter=All)

[Sorting with sort icons](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=How+To%3a+Improve+Column+Sort+Presentation+for+an+ASP.NET+GridView&Filter=All)

Some more themes

https://web.archive.org/web/20140702022550/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/10/a_yui_datatable_styled_gridvie.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20150201190248/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/11/5_gridview_themes_based_on_goo.html

[image]

Comment: +1 for matt's gridview themes based on google. I've practically used that it rocks.

Comment: mattserbeseth is no longer there

Comment: as of 7.23.2015 none of the mattberseth links appear to work.

Answer (score 5):

Matts site has been hijacked and you cannot get to the resources using these links. See http://forums.asp.net/t/1755110.aspx/1/10

Answer (score 1):

Matt Berseth's Page: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/11/5_gridview_themes_based_on_goo.html
Source Code can be downloaded here after hacked website: http://t.co/J9UJetHb