# Set column width of Gridview inside rowdatabound event.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have the following piece of code. I did not define any boundfields in my gridview. I am retrieving data using sql queries in my aspx.cs file instead. Is it possible to adjust the width of each column 0, 1, 2? Are there any ways that I can look into? I have tried a lot of ways but it is still not working. Please help!

```
<asp:GridView ID="surgicalGridView" runat="server"
    CaptionAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Justify" 
    DataKeyNames="id" onselectedindexchanged="surgicalGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
    ToolTip="Excel File Download Tool" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" Width="854px">

     <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
       <Columns>
       <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Download" 
               ControlStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
<ControlStyle ForeColor="Blue"></ControlStyle>
           </asp:CommandField>
       </Columns>
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <HeaderStyle   BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that on the `OnRowDataBound` event of the `gridview`.

```
protected void surgicalGridView_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         e.Row.Cells[0].Width = new Unit("200px");
         e.Row.Cells[1].Width = new Unit("400px");
         // and so on
    } 
}
```

Add this to your `Gridview` Markup

```
<asp:GridView ...............................
        onrowdatabound="surgicalGridView_RowDataBound">    // just add this event and execute the above code
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I have to call this method to change every time the page load? How do i exactly execute this method? thanks!

Comment: its not a method, its a `gridview` event and NO you do not have to write it on page_load or anywhere. see my updates on the answer

Comment: so sorry i'm new to using gridview! so how exactly should i use it!

Comment: alright....`gridview` has an event called `onrowdatabound` where ypu can initialize `gridview` properties..So like i have updated in my answer..add that event as shown and directly copy paste that code..it will work for you...:)...you can set whatever `width` you want

Answer (score 0):

As grid is rendered as `table` `tr` and `dt` so you can use the css class for the grid. 
There you can set the width of your columns.
In classes your can use like `td`, `td+td`,`td+td+td` etc

According to the post
[.NET Gridview themes examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973240/net-gridview-themes-examples)

Check out these links.

http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/index.php?css=69#r69

http://mattberseth2.com/demo/ has lot of gridview customizations with code download.

[Paging](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=Using%20a%20DataPager%20with%20the%20GridView%20Control%20-%20Implementing%20IPageableItemContainer&Filter=All)

[Paging With Slider](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=A%20Slider%20DataPager%20with%20Dynamic%20Tooltips&Filter=All)

[Sorting with sort icons](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=How%20To:%20Improve%20Column%20Sort%20Presentation%20for%20an%20ASP.NET%20GridView&Filter=All)

Some more themes

http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=A+YUI+DataTable+Styled+GridView&Filter=All
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/11/5_gridview_themes_based_on_goo.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [mattberseth.com](http://mattberseth.com/WindowsLiveWriter/FiveGridViewThemesbasedon_11611/image%7B0%7D%5B5%5D.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below. I have a grid that has 2 defined columns and the rest are bound dynamically. I don't know why setting the column with (e.Row.Cells[0].Width = new Unit("200px");) didn't work, but I found an alternative. Also, my grid has sorting enabled, therefore the linkbutton code.

```
const int FirstControl = 0;
const int GriDefinedFieldsCount = 2;

protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
         int col = 0;
         foreach (DataColumn dc in SiteManager.Reports.ReportData.Columns)
         {
             if (dc.ColumnName == "Notes")
             {
                 LinkButton lnk = (e.Row.Cells[col + GriDefinedFieldsCount].Controls[FirstControl] as LinkButton);
                 lnk.Width = Unit.Pixel(300);
             }
             col += 1;
         }
     }
```